# Switch from Mysql to MongoDB 200 millions rows

Tags: mysql, mongodb, bigdata

We are trying to move from mysql to mongodb.
mysql structure is 
id_src int
id_dest int
unique key : id_src,id_dest

They are about 200 millions rows in mysql

data exemple :
{id_src,id_dest} {1,2} {1,3} {1,10} {2,3} {2,10} {4,3}

We need to retrive data : 
{id_dest,count} {3,3} {10,2} {2,1}

I started to repoduced the structure of mysql in mongodb.
Insert performance were huge (very good)  : about 1 hour to insert 200 millions rows.

But I needed to use map reduce to get the group by. Map reduce took about 1 hour.

So I tried to create an other mongodb structure : 
{id_dest,{id_src1,id_src2}}

Each document can have hundred thousand of id_src.

Here is my insert.php code

```
$res=mysql_unbuffered_query("select * from ids limit 10000100");  
while ($tab=mysql_fetch_array($res)) {  
$collection->update(array('_id'=>(int)$tab['id_dest']),array('$push' => array('src'=>(int)$tab['id_src'])),array("upsert" => true));  
}
```

But in that case performance are very bad, only few update per seconds.

Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: If 1h is "huge" for 200m rows, then let me ask you this: How long did inserting 200m rows take you in MySQL?

Comment: When I said "huge", I was saying "very very good". But my problem was with the map reduce time to get the "group by" which is acceptable but not perfect to us. I wondered if a new document model, using mongodb feature (multivalue field), wasn't clever than just reproduce mysql data structure.

Comment: I see. Let's wait for a good answer, then :-)

Comment: thanks @lukas for helping me get my point through

Comment: MapReduce in Mongo has a currently a major "drawback": it use only one cpu for the moment...

Comment: @AurelienB I created two shard on the same machine, which, I think, enable the use of two core

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First things first, Map / Reduce is not designed for real-time analysis. Additionally, MongoDB is currently limited to one core for M/R which will slow things down even more.

So if you're going to use M/R to get data, it will not be "real-time" it will be updated every X minutes (or hours).

There are two efficient approaches here:

1. Incremental M/R
2. Real-time counters

**Option #1: Incremental M/R**

For this option you run the M/R once for all of the data. Then, going forward, you only run M/R on the modified data. If you have 200M documents now, you may have 210M documents next (which means that M/R gets even slower). But if you only have to run new/changed documents, then it should take much less than 1 hour.

Take a look at the `reduce` output option in the docs [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce).

Again the premise is that you only M/R the relevant data and the system "re-reduces" against the existing data. In this way you get an "incremental" M/R.

**Option #2: Real-Time counters**

In this method, you have two collections: one for your data, a second for the result of the "summary". When you insert into data, you also do an increment on the summary.

Assume you have this data:

```
Main Collection
{src: 1, dest: 2}
{src: 1, dest: 3}
{src: 1, dest: 10}
{src: 2, dest: 3}
{src: 2, dest: 10}
{src: 4, dest: 3}

Summary Collection
{dest: 3, count: 3}
{dest: 10, count: 2}
{dest: 2, count: 1}
```

You receive a new piece of data `{src: 5, dest: 2}`. You would do two updates:

```
db.main.insert({src: 5, dest: 2});
db.summary.update({dest: 2}, { $inc : { count: 1 } }, true); // upsert true
```

Here's your new data:

```
Main Collection
{src: 1, dest: 2}
...
{src: 4, dest: 3}
{src: 5, dest: 2}

Summary Collection
{dest: 3, count: 3}
{dest: 10, count: 2}
{dest: 2, count: 2}
```

You'll notice that we've updated our summary: `{dest: 2, count: 2}`.

Obviously, there are trade-offs here. You need more updates/inserts (2x), but you get real-time counters. Now, there are no transactions in MongoDB, so you'll have to decide on a strategy for ensuring that both updates happen. There are lots of ways to do this which I cannot go into here (see message queues for one method).

Comment: I implemented the realtime solution you suggested during the last few hours. I just get great results. Updating the summary collection is very fast and nearly doesn't slow down performance, and I get Real Time update counter. Thanks !